# More efficient way to select element if it exists, then do something with it in vanilla JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm doing some jQuery to Vanilla JS conversions on my website. In jQuery I can do this:

```
$("#nav-menu>ul>li.active").removeClass("active");
```

which, all in one line, will remove the class 'active' from any <li> elements which have it (there would only be one). If no <li> elements have that class, there are no errors and my script continues running.

However, in Vanilla JS, if I do this:

```
document.querySelector('#nav-menu>ul>li.active').classList.remove('active');
```

and there are currently no <li> elements with the 'actove' class, I get the following error and my script stops running:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read prperties of null (reading 'classlist')
```

I can get around this like so:

```
var active = document.querySelector('#nav-menu>ul>li.active');
if(active) {
  active.classList.remove('active');
}
```

But I'm wondering if there is a better, shorter way to do this(i.e. select an element if it exists, then do something with it)? Is there a shorthand way or way to do it in fewer lines, etc?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: [Optional chaining (`?.`)](//developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining)?

Comment: Please note that your jQuery approach removes the class from every `li` with the `active` class.
Your vanilla JS approach however only processes the first `li.active` found in the DOM. To get all matching elements use [`querySelectorAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use optional chaining for this purpose, which can access properties or go into a chained function call only if the expression on the left is not undefined nor null.

```
document.querySelector('#nav-menu>ul>li.active')?.classList.remove('active');
```